# Jersey inject instance into Resource

Tags: java, jersey

I'm trying to create a Jersey Resource that allows me to reuse an ElasticSearch TransportClient. So I would like to use a single instance of TransportClient over all Resources that require it. So far I've got this:

Resource:

```
@Path("/request")
public class ConfigurationResource {

    private final TransportClient transportClient;

    @Inject
    public ConfigurationResource(TransportClient transportClient)
    {    
        this.transportClient = transportClient;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String AlarmStatus(){
        if(transportClient != null)
            return "Not NULL! ID: ";
        else
            return "NULL :(";
    }
}
```

Binding:

```
public class WebMainBinder extends AbstractBinder {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        TransportClient transportClient = null;
        try {
            transportClient = TransportClient.builder().build()
                    .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        bind(transportClient).to(TransportClient.class);
    }
}
```

Main Application:

```
@ApplicationPath("service")
public class WebMain extends ResourceConfig {
    public WebMain(){
        register(new WebMainBinder());
        packages(true, "com.eniacdevelopment.EniacHome.Resources");
    }
}
```

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>com.eniacdevelopment.EniacHome.Application.WebMain</servlet-name>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>com.eniacdevelopment.EniacHome.Application.WebMain</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I've also tried using a factory like so:

```
public class TransportClientFactory implements Factory<TransportClient> {

    private TransportClient transportClient;

    @Override
    public TransportClient provide() {
        if(this.transportClient == null){
            try {
                transportClient = TransportClient.builder().build()
                        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
            }
        }

        return transportClient;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose(TransportClient transportClient) {
    }
}
```

And then binding it this way:

```
bindFactory(TransportClientFactory.class)
    .to(TransportClient.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

But no success. I keep on getting Unsatisfied dependencies for type TransportClient with qualifiers @Default.

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright got it to work:

When I at first tried to deploy the app to glassfish it complained about some guava dependency. I swapped the Guava jar in glassfish/modules with the one maven had installed and got it to deploy. It may have something to do with that. No guarentees here.

I decided to drop the whole glassfish stuff and start from scratch. On the jersey introduction page there's this maven archetype that can be isntalled like so:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-grizzly2
-DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service 
-Dpackage=com.example 
-DarchetypeVersion=2.24
```

Starting from there helped me out.

Answer (score 1):

I've found Jersey's DI container functionality pretty unpleasant. I prefer to use Guice for managing my DI, so if you're open to using Guice, you can see how to wire up Jersey and Guice to collaborate in this demo project: https://bitbucket.org/marshallpierce/guice-jaxrs-examples. The `common` subproject has the shared logic, and there are other subprojects for the jersey and resteasy specific parts.